# Single out values from a column to a chart

Tags: excel, vba, office-2010

I've made this code in VBA to create a pie chart from the values of a single sheet page (these values were imported from a students list database), the values I want to convert into a pie chart are related to the sex column, the values on this column can either be 'M' or 'F', this is the code I tried:

```
Sub CriarGrafico()
Set graficos = Sheets(3).ChartObjects
On Error Resume Next
If Not graficos Is Nothing Then graficos.Delete
'elimina os graficos existentes na folha 8
Set Grafico = graficos.Add(0, 100, 500, 250)
Grafico.Chart.ChartWizard _
Source:=Sheets(2).Range("E7:E13"), _
Gallery:=xlPie, _
CategoryLabels:=1, _
SeriesLabels:=1, _
HasLegend:=True
```

I have two problems here, first of all, my range doesn't seem to be working, I'm guessing it's because I'm only using values from one single collumn, secondly, if I do attempt to include a second column, the chart is not agglomerating the M and F values (so if I have 3 tudents that are male and 2 female students, the chart displays 5 values)

I want my chart to simply display 2 results, one for the M value and F value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your input looks like this:

```
Student1    M
Student2    F
Student3    F
Student4    F
Student5    M
Student6    M
Student7    F
```

and you want something like this:

[image]

The chart will not "agglomerate M and F", i.e. it won't calculate the total number of M's and F's for you. You have to do that yourself, for example using `=COUNTIF($E$7:$E$13,"=M")` and `=COUNTIF($E$7:$E$13,"=F")`, which would result in something like this:

```
M    3
F    4
```

This you can plot as a pie chart like the one above.

Without seeing your sheet I can't tell you why your "range doesn't work", but this code definitely works for me:

```
Dim Grafico As ChartObject
Dim s As Series
Set Grafico = Sheets(3).ChartObjects.Add(0, 100, 500, 250)
With Grafico.Chart
    .ChartType = xlPie
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("G8:H9")
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=Sheets(3).Name
End With
```